# Java chat socket milion clients

Tags: java, database, architecture

I would like to know the architecture of real time chat for millions of users like whatsapp.

**I implemented a chat but I need to use more servers to handle more clients**

I read another question, but I still have doubts about.
Tell me if what I say is correct:

Clients connect to load balancer that decide to give connection to one of the whatsapp servers.
Example ClientA connect to Server1,
        ClientB connect to Server2,

**-If ClientA wants to communicate with ClientB, sends a message to the Server1 ,now, this how do you know in which server is ClientB ?  Maintaining the scalability to millions of users )**

**How to implement a chat to handle millions of users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the database (or any other persistence system) where all the input from the clients gets stored.  Usually in these scales, a [key-value NoSql Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) is suitable, like [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [Amazon Dynamo](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/?nc2=h_m1), or [Google Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview).
These databases are optimal for fast insert and fetch by PK only.

All the servers need to be stateless, so Client A connects to Server A and sends a text message and destination client Id.  This gets stored in the DB.  Then, client B connets to Server B which goes to the database and retrieves the text.

Comment: Thank you but if I use a big Database if i have milion of users each servers must search among millions of queries which is what you want.This takes time

Comment: If you fetch one row by PK (like client-id) then the database engine can accomodate for that.  All the big social apps use this architecture.

Comment: Here is a very detailed descrption of the architecture used by instagram from their tech blog.  They use redis (open source key-value nosql db) for their main feed. they also use traditional RDBMS and cloud storage, just read all about it   http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances

Comment: Right, Thank you!  I can make more concurrent requests to the database?

Comment: I read, thank you. One last question: A server must continue to interrogate the database to see if you are receiving a new query or there is a solution?